# absolute position divs with image background

Tags: css, google-chrome

For past several hours I try to figure out why only one of absolute positioned divs with image backgroung appears. Here is my css code for absolute positioned div

```
.nastip {
position: absolute;
width: 64px;
height: 20px;
background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/addons.heroku.com/catalogs/287/small.png);
right: -36px;
bottom: 2px;
}
```

Here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/6uAvq/

I need to display both images in absolute positioned divs.

I use chrome browser. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolumn in your css prior to `.aakcia` rule  which terminates any more styles appearing after that.

```
; /*Remove this*/
.aakcia {
    position: absolute;
    width: 64px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/addons.heroku.com/catalogs/287/small.png);
    right: -36px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx8MF/)**

Comment: OMG, thank you. I was about to throw my pc out of the window:) so stupid.

Comment: @user1031743 you are welcome.. i think you probably added this rule later which was already terminated by a semi column.

Comment: If you [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your CSS _before_ asking, you can avoid unnecessary questions …